# How to select specfic data from a array html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

I want to display specfic data i have array as follows

```
 let questions = [
   {
   numb: 1,
   question: "What does HTML stand for?",
   answer: "Hyper Text Markup Language",
   options: [
   "Hyper Text Preprocessor",
   "Hyper Text Markup Language",
   "Hyper Text Multiple Language",
   "Hyper Tool Multi Language"
   ]
   },
   {
   numb: 2,
   question: "What does CSS stand for?",
   answer: "Cascading Style Sheet",
   options: [
   "Common Style Sheet",
   "Colorful Style Sheet",
   "Computer Style Sheet",
   "Cascading Style Sheet"
   ]
   },
   {
   numb: 3,
   question: "What does PHP stand for?",
   answer: "Hypertext Preprocessor",
   options: [
   "Hypertext Preprocessor",
   "Hypertext Programming",
   "Hypertext Preprogramming",
   "Hometext Preprocessor"
   ]
   },
```

From this i want to display all question and answer only.
Like

*What does HTML stand for* - *Hyper Text Markup Language*

*What does CSS stand for* - *Cascading Style Sheet*

*What does PHP stand for* - *Hypertext Preprocessor*

I am a noob to this any one help to print all questions Answer

Comment: What does *respected answer* mean? Also, you can't just drop JavaScript in your HTML without it being inside `scrip` tags and really that's not how to do it in 2021 anyway. Before we get into your specific question, I think you should learn some JavaScript basics.

Comment: I want to show all question and answer

Comment: Ok, so I think what you are saying is that you want to use the array of objects as a data source to then produce corresponding questions with the potential answers to each. There is quite a bit more to it than what you've shown and this kind of question is not really appropriate for Stack Overflow. We expect that you'll do your research before posting. You need to learn quite a bit about looping through arrays and objects, creating dynamic elements, and appending to the document to make something like this work.

Comment: I know no one do my work. I searched and made quiz using html and css. But i am literature a student i don't know more about this. I am working  for 8hrs to fix a small mistake. Finally i found this forum. Did you know to fix this please help me.

Comment: While I understand your frustration, your code doesn't need a simple fix. The two small pieces of JavaScript you have in your attempt are incorrect. What you need is a complete solution created -- that's not what we do here.

Comment: , ok i will study to create that please guide me some topic or any other question helpful to me

Comment: As I said in my earlier comment: *You need to learn quite a bit about looping through arrays and objects, creating dynamic elements, and appending to the document to make something like this work.*

Comment: I quitting my work i don't know more about JavaScript , i am completely newbie

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're looking to simply print the question and answer of each object you could use `forEach` as shown below.

```js
let questions = [{
    numb: 1,
    question: "What does HTML stand for?",
    answer: "Hyper Text Markup Language",
    options: [
      "Hyper Text Preprocessor",
      "Hyper Text Markup Language",
      "Hyper Text Multiple Language",
      "Hyper Tool Multi Language"
    ]
  },
  {
    numb: 2,
    question: "What does CSS stand for?",
    answer: "Cascading Style Sheet",
    options: [
      "Common Style Sheet",
      "Colorful Style Sheet",
      "Computer Style Sheet",
      "Cascading Style Sheet"
    ]
  },
  {
    numb: 3,
    question: "What does PHP stand for?",
    answer: "Hypertext Preprocessor",
    options: [
      "Hypertext Preprocessor",
      "Hypertext Programming",
      "Hypertext Preprogramming",
      "Hometext Preprocessor"
    ]
  }
];

questions.forEach(question => console.log(`${question.question} - ${question.answer}`));
```

As far as adding this to an HTML section you could create a [documentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) and append paragraph tags to it via [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild). From there just append the fragment to the section tag.

```js
let questions = [{
    numb: 1,
    question: "What does HTML stand for?",
    answer: "Hyper Text Markup Language",
    options: [
      "Hyper Text Preprocessor",
      "Hyper Text Markup Language",
      "Hyper Text Multiple Language",
      "Hyper Tool Multi Language"
    ]
  },
  {
    numb: 2,
    question: "What does CSS stand for?",
    answer: "Cascading Style Sheet",
    options: [
      "Common Style Sheet",
      "Colorful Style Sheet",
      "Computer Style Sheet",
      "Cascading Style Sheet"
    ]
  },
  {
    numb: 3,
    question: "What does PHP stand for?",
    answer: "Hypertext Preprocessor",
    options: [
      "Hypertext Preprocessor",
      "Hypertext Programming",
      "Hypertext Preprogramming",
      "Hometext Preprocessor"
    ]
  }
];

const section = document.getElementById('section');

const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

questions.forEach(question => {
  const paragraph = document.createElement('p');
  
  paragraph.innerText = `${question.question} - ${question.answer}`;
  
  fragment.appendChild(paragraph);
});

section.appendChild(fragment);
```

```html
<section id="section"></section>
```

Comment: How i print this in html section, thanks for these guide

Comment: While I know you are trying to be helpful, this kind of question doesn't belong on SO and we tend not to answer them to avoid more of these kinds of questions showing up here. We have guidelines on how to ask questions and what kinds of questions should be asked.

Comment: If this is truly the case I would think that closing the question would deem more helpful than downvoting answers for the sake of.

Comment: I have voted to close the question and suggest you do so as well. But, by downvoting we really can deter answers to poor questions.

Comment: I unfortunately can't agree with the latter half of your approach. If someone has a solution to a problem and it does in fact provide a solid answer it shouldn't be penalized. You're essentially taking your anger out on other users because you don't agree on how a question was asked. As far as OPs question, I've seen worse. He's provided **some** code and despite his lack of clarity it still deems worthy of a response. How else will he learn as a beginner?

Comment: This has nothing to do with anger. [We do have guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question and one of those is to search and research before posting. This question (and many others like it) don't reflect that. It's a user who is exasperated because they don't know anything about what they are doing and are asking for a solution. That is not an appropriate question for SO and should be discouraged. When we answer these questions, it just encourages more of the same, which we don't want.

Comment: @fanmmatgroup I've updated my answer. Give it a look.